# How can I run auto datetime in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, datetime, insert

I use C# .NET

I need run auto `datetime` in my project and save in SQL Server

**Exam.**

In SQL Server

```
Datetime    | workDate
-------------------------
25-10-2012  | work
26-10-2012  | work
28-10-2012  | work
```

In my project, I'm searching datetime between 25-28

I need program output

```
25-10-2012  work
26-10-2012  work
27-10-2012  null
28-10-2012  work
```

But now I get:

```
25-10-2012  work
26-10-2012  work
28-10-2012  work
```

Because my data save status work only when status don't work it's not save in database.

How can I use insert value null, show data to my project and save in SQL Server?

Thanks For your Time :).

Comment: You have some code of what you have already tried?

Comment: i haven't code,because i'm develop project old from others.

Organization need create project new from scope project old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a recursive CTE to generate a list of days.

```
; with  AllDays as
        (
        select  cast('2012-10-25' as date) as dt -- Start date
        union all
        select  dateadd(day, 1, dt)
        from    AllDays
        where   dt < '2012-10-28' -- End date
        )
select  convert(varchar(10), ad.dt, 105)
,       workDate
from    AllDays ad
left join
        Table1 t1
on      t1.Datetime = convert(varchar(10), ad.dt, 105)
```

[Example at SQL FiIddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a5e2e/11/0)  The `convert` changes the SQL Server date to a `varchar(10)` in [format 105, the Italian format](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp).